# Find the next letter in the below series

Tags: letter-sequence

I got a question during an interview in a company and I still could not find out the solution. Kindly help me to solve this.

> H,A,H,L,U,?

Comment: You mean "letter", not "alphabet". An alphabet is a set of letters. Not the first time I see this mistake. What translator did you use? May be worth sending some feedback.

Comment: Was the question asked in English?  Because these letters could be the first letters of a common set in another language eg( M,T,W,T,F, ?)  would be S for Saturday.

Comment: 8,1,8,12,21,?   positions of the above letters in alphabet. i need to find the next position in the series

Comment: what was the job? it might be relevant :)

Comment: for an IT job. its same like number series.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I think it's not so much a mistake as a dialect difference: in Indian English, "alphabet" means what "letter" means in most varieties of English.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan How interesting! Thanks. I wonder what other differences there might be (and how they call a British English alphabet).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the answer is

> **L**
>
>  This is based on the fact that the first and last letters of each triplet is the same. For example, `HAH`, `LUL`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is my random solution

H,A,H,L,U,___

The answer is:

> W

> Sequence is `8, 1, 8, 12, 21` - ignoring the first as red herring, the distance between each value is `[7,4,9]` (for example, 8 - 1 = 7, 12 - 8 = 4, etc.). The distance between those values shows a growing sequence of odd, prime numbers: [3,5] (for example, 7-4 = 3, 9-4 = 5).

> However, it seems it oscillates between subtraction and addition. 7 - 4 = 3, but 4 + 5 = 9. I'd assume the next sequence would be `7`, which is an odd prime number. And the next step requires subtraction, so it is: 9 - 7 = 2. Therefore, the next number would jump by 2 units (21 + 2). Which ends up in 23, which is the letter `W`

Comment: If you allow for such complicatedness in the answer, starting from such a small data set, then there are hundreds of similar valid answers.